# Worklight 6.2 wlapp deployment gives error java heap space

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

Environment details:

1.OS Linux

2.Worklight 6.2 in clustered environment

3.WAS ND 8.5.5

4.DB2 10.5

Deployed Sample war file.

Deploying a sample-common.wlapp file which is of size 3mb gives "java heap space". If a file (.wlapp) of size less then 2 MB deploying successfully.

I tried setting the JVM heap sizes to about 2048mb on the servers. Still no luck.

[image: Error on worklight console activity log]

> `Transaction 2
>       type: UPLOAD_APPLICATION
>       status: FAILURE
>       dateCreated : 2014-10-09T10:43:28.943Z
>       dateUpdated: 2014-10-09T10:44:07.932Z
>       server: WebSphere:ihsCell01/wl2Node01/worklight2
>       description: 
>           appVersionsDeployed: 
>               1 :
>                   applicationName: AppDelegate
>                   environment: android
>                   version: 1.0
>           filename: AppDelegate-android-1.0.wlapp
>       errors: 
>           1 :
>               mbeanName: WebSphere:cell=ihsCell01,name=Dubai,node=wl1Node01,process=worklight1,type=ProjectManagement_RAK
>               date: 2014-10-09T10:44:03.766Z
>               phase: PREPARE
>               code: FAILURE
>               exception: OutOfMemoryError
>               details: Java heap space
>           2 :
>               mbeanName: WebSphere:cell=ihsCell01,name=Dubai,node=wl2Node01,process=worklight2,type=ProjectManagement_RAK
>               date: 2014-10-09T10:44:07.803Z
>               phase: PREPARE
>               code: FAILURE
>               exception: OutOfMemoryError
>               details: Java heap space

`

Server Logs

```
[10/9/14 4:10:18:872 PDT] 0000010c BaseTransacti E   RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception
                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.handleAdminFault(SOAPConnectorClient.java:948)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplateOnce(SOAPConnectorClient.java:916)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:682)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:672)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:658)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:480)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminClientImpl.invoke(AdminClientImpl.java:224)
at com.worklight.common.util.jmx.WASRuntimeMBeanHandler$AdminClientMBeanServerConnection.invoke(WASRuntimeMBeanHandler.java:524)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$InvokeHandler.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:146)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:160)
at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:259)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.deployApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.prepareMBean(ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.java:503)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:75)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:43)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:931)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:773)
```

[10/9/14 4:10:20:275 PDT] 0000010b BaseTransacti E   RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception
                                 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.handleAdminFault(SOAPConnectorClient.java:948)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplateOnce(SOAPConnectorClient.java:916)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:682)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:672)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:658)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:480)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminClientImpl.invoke(AdminClientImpl.java:224)
    at com.worklight.common.util.jmx.WASRuntimeMBeanHandler$AdminClientMBeanServerConnection.invoke(WASRuntimeMBeanHandler.java:524)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$InvokeHandler.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:146)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:160)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:259)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.deployApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.prepareMBean(ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.java:503)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:75)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:931)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:773)

Answer (score 1):

That should be fixed in a recent IFIX at https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/myportal/product/other_software/ibm_worklight?productContext=-1445909362#